# Read text from a file and load a new string from a row every 24 hour

Tags: php, text, line

After some hours of research I made this script:

```
function get_string_on_interval($strings, $interval) {
    return $strings[round((time()/$interval - floor(time()/$interval)) * sizeof($strings))];
}

echo get_string_on_interval(file('matlista.txt'), 60*60*24);
```

In this `matlista.txt` I have a specific word on each row/line. 
This script shows a string from this text file on my site but the problem is that it doesn't start showing from `index 1` (which is row/line 1) it starts from the `line 46`. 
I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I want this script to read from `line 1` and after 24 hours it should go to `line 2` and so on and display the different lines every 24 hour. This script starts to show `line 46` and continues from there, I can't find the problem.

Comment: `This script starts to show line 46` why not? suppose that 46 days are already passed since the 'start' of the script. Does it matter whether it starts from 1 or 46?

Comment: Hi, something like this would be easier managed in a database, it's difficult to seek to specific lines unless you use SPL.  Generally speaking you don't want to let a script rune for > a few minutes.

Comment: Whenever I add a new line to the matlista.txt it goes up a line to read from. So it starts to read from line 45 if I add line 47.
Yes I want it to start from 1 since I have a specific order I want them to be shown.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I've been searching around for a solution for this problem I have. This is the only solution for me there's no other.

Comment: this might give you a hint - " * sizeof($strings) " times the size of the strings?

Comment: @sameizad - so you cant store this data in a database, with a check field to see if you read it already, then you read the first un-read record and check it off.  That is how i would do it, but with a cron job.

Comment: "this might give you a hint - " * sizeof($strings) " times the size of the strings? " 

You saved my night man, that fixed it I think. Now I just have to wait 24hours to see if this actually worked. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(
'line1',
'line2',
'line3'
);

function get_string_on_interval($strings, $interval)
{
   $startTime = '2014-03-11 18:14:00';
   return $strings[floor((time() - strtotime($startTime)) / $interval) 
                % count($strings)]; 
}

echo get_string_on_interval($data, 10);
```

And `$startTime` is the datetime from which you want to 'count' the lines (when the first line is shown). Example should change the line every 10 seconds.

Comment: I think I fixed it, your example is without reading in the textfile right? I just write the lines in the code?

Comment: @sameizad yes, it takes data from array. also it sets the time/date when the first line is shown (should be in the past), otherwise number of your intervals are counted from the Unix epoch (1970) and it could start from anything.

Comment: Awesome, I'll wait 24 hours to see if the current script I'm using works. If it doesn't I'm surely going to use this thank you.

Comment: @sameizad you do not have to wait for 24 hours, you can setup like a one minute.

Comment: The thing is the script I'm using currently was done exacly 00:00 now and I don't want to screw up the time. But if you are 100% sure that your script will work I can try it right now.

Comment: @sameizad you are not going to screw anything up. as I wrote, the time() gives seconds from the start of Unix epoch (midnight of January 1, 1970). that is why the counter 'restarts' at midnight.

Comment: So if I want it to reset at 00:00 in GMT + 1 what should start time be?

Comment: is the starttime server based? Like is it going after the servers time?

Comment: @sameizad yes, by default, if timezone is not listed, it will start from the local timezone of the server (this option is in php.ini).

Comment: If I have a array of 50 words I just put the starttime and then I dont have to change it anymore since its just looping through the array with the specific time that I set there right? Start time is just a exact start time for the array to start?

Comment: Not to start, but the moment from which it 'started'. Just to set the time in the past when the first line 'was' shown instead of 1970.

Comment: I dont get it, so I can just put a time there that is after 1970? So if I put 2013-04-11 01:06:00 it should work? (its the current time here)

Comment: Ok nvm the last question, I want it to be every 24 hour in changing time. 60*60*24 should make it change every 24 hour?

Comment: Too many questions. Why won't you try and look? you do not have to run on the main page of the website, you can create a new one and experiment as many times as you want. `its the current time here` it is not a current time - not 2013, and format is YYYY-MM-DD