# PHP: "Do something after N days"

Tags: php

Basically, my idea is to introduce a timing structure in PHP that would, let's say alter the main encryption algorithm of the system every N days.

```
$key32 = pack('H*', "bcb04b7e103a0cd8b54763051cef08bc55abe029fdebae5e1d417e2ffb2a00a3"); # 32 byte
$key24 = pack('H*', "dd0255b51151b71427984aa74ae4f1993b7400c3d184ad02");                 # 24 byte
$key16 = pack('H*', "13196c5ecdac5413148ba11469448474");                                 # 16 byte

# show key size use either 16, 24 or 32 byte keys for AES-128, 192
# and 256 respectively
$key_size =  strlen($key24);
echo "Key size: " . $key_size . "\n";

$plaintext = "Ruffles";

# create a random IV to use with CBC encoding
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

# creates a cipher text compatible with AES (Rijndael block size = 128)
# to keep the text confidential 
# only suitable for encoded input that never ends with value 00h
# (because of default zero padding)
$ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192, $key24,
                             $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

# prepend the IV for it to be available for decryption
$ciphertext = $iv . $ciphertext;

# encode the resulting cipher text so it can be represented by a string
$ciphertext_base64 = base64_encode($ciphertext);
```

Though doing something like this:

```
   if (date('d.m.y')=='08.11.14') {
        $encryption = 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192';
        $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key24,
                                 $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
   }
```

cannot solve the problem since the file has to be loaded on that date and besides, the file should just be encrypting user passwords for direct insertion in the database afterwards. Should I just make a cron job instead?

Comment: of course cron job is a solution.

Comment: Look here, idea is the same - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724941/read-text-from-a-file-and-load-a-new-string-from-a-row-every-24-hour/26725040#26725040